# Gaussians in MATLAB

Tags: function, matlab, math, gaussian

If I want to create a gaussian function and then find the value at a particular point, what functions would I use in MATLAB. Sorry if this is supposed to be obvious but somehow I couldn't find it by googling.

Comment: Why is this being downvoted? I searched for gaussian instead of normal so I didn't see the normpdf function. That seems pretty reasonable to me and I think other people might have that same problem.

Comment: i did nt downvote you but i think it is justifiable that such qns are downvoted. It is obvious that you should check the matlab help. A search for "gaussian" or "normal" would have led you to the right function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the normal distribution pdf:

http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/normpdf.html